# Cannot connect to database - python ODBC

Tags: python, odbc, pyodbc

I am struggling to connect to an ODBC DSN using python 3. The ODBC driver is a read only driver from a SCADA package vendor not a standard MS or Oracle driver type.

I have tried pyodbc:

```
import pyodbc
...
  connectionString = 'dsn=myDSN'
  connection = pyodbc.connect(connectionString)
```

Which yields the error:

```
('HY000', '[HY000] [Simba][ODBC] Not enough information provided to connection to data source and specified to not prompt for more information. (10042) (SQLDriverConnect); [HY000] [Simba][ODBC] Not enough information provided to connection to data source and specified to not prompt for more information. (10042)')
```

I have tried odbc:

```
import odbc
...
  conn = odbc.odbc('myDSN')
```

Which yields the similar error:

```
[Simba][ODBC] Not enough information provided to connection to data source and specified to not prompt for more information. in LOGIN
```

I have third party .net forms program which I decompliled and I can see uses a standard System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection with the same simple connection string as the pyodbc method above and it works fine...

I have been over the pyodbc documentation but I can't see any other parameters or attributes I need to set to get this to work, or at least have it prompt for the extra information I am not supplying.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Thanks in advance.

Mike.

Answer (score 0):

Try do to like this:

```
sql_conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=10.10.10.10;DATABASE=test; trusted_connection=yes')
```